# Anylogic Retrieve Multiple Agents (Boxes) in Single Run of Forklift

Tags: anylogic

I have a model [Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEze4.png) of a small warehouse with a storage system. Using the material handling library, I've successfully injected agents into the system. The issue is when I try to pull multiple boxes on the same "run" of the forklift.

I've tried sending a batch of boxes into the retrieve node but it pulls one at a time(Or the combined batch). The other issue is that the boxes it is going to pull is random — Much like a grocery store. In my current model: I have the "retrieve" block destination set to null and for the transporter to stay where it is on release. I feel like there is a "for" loop iterating in the pickup loop. Is there a way to send a number of agents to the retrieve block to be picked in the same block?.

Comment: I think this should be a duplicate of. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68845403/in-anylogic-how-can-i-model-truck-that-deliver-orders-to-multiple-clients?rq=2